# MySql - Table permissions

Tags: mysql

I have to create a table in MySql that have 2 Property :

1 . Allow `insert` AND `read`

2 . Deny `delete` and `update`

How can i do this ? is this possible to do with phpmyadmin ?

Thanks

Comment: Usually the roles permission is assigned to a certain user for certain database than to a table.

Comment: @apomene thank you . but please let me know how can i do this with roles ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that for a USER.

`Grant select,insert on Db_name.Tb_name to 'USER';`